# when calling "JRequest::get('FilterForm')" result is empty

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, filter

When calling the method `$this->filterForm    = JRequest::getVar('FilterForm');`, I get an empty result.
But checking the com_banners component on the same system shows a result. What can I do to get it working?

Comment: `JRequest` is deprecated and soon to be removed. Please use this: https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to retrieve an input:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$this->filterForm = $jinput->get('FilterForm', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

TIP: Take into account that if your don't specify a *default_value*, it will return null when no value is detected. If your don't specify a *filter*, it will apply a strict filter, CMD, for commands (It allows a-z, 0-9, underscore, dot, dash. It also removes leading dots from result).

Comment: The result is still NULL (when I remove the 'filter' and the 'default_value'). I think, I have something completly wrong. Thats why I get no result.

Comment: @DreiBaer - In which case the issue will be with a different part of your code.

Comment: WHat do you mean with "case"? I have implemented it Component-File -> Controller (with constructor) -> View.